# Run console application automatically in windows

Tags: windows, console-application

Is it possible to automatically run a console application on a particular time in a day.

With out set up any sheduler !

Answer (score 0):

Not without any scheduler; *something* needs to invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can write a separate app that runs on startup and starts your app for you at the desired time. This would mean that this background app would always be open.

Using the scheduler would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

If with "set up any scheduler" you refer to not installing something to do the schedule, there is no need to do that. Windows include it own scheduler.